# Adding a reference between typescript projects for unit testing in visual studio

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, unit-testing, typescript

I have two typescript projects in which one is a unit test project. I am using Mocha to run these unit test and I am using VS2015. I want to add a reference from my AuthenticationApiTS to AuthenticationApiTSTest project. I tried out many of the ways suggested, but nothing seems to work. Below is my project structure.

[This is my folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T1YTc.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

say in your `package.json` your project name is `AuthenticationApiTS`

run `npm link` in `AuthenticationApiTS` folder

run `npm link AuthenticationApiTS` in `AuthenticationApiTSTest` folder.

then you can use `AuthenticationApiTS` like it's a npm installed pacakge.

Comment: I get this error registry returned 404 for get on https //registry.npmjs.org/AutheticationApiTS when running  npm link AuthenticationApiTS

Comment: @j-s did you have `AutheticationApiTS` as package name in your `AutheticationApiTS` package.json,   the package name has to be consistent with what you `npm link` for.

Comment: yes I did, It say AutheticationApiTS is not in the registry

Comment: Thanks I got it done. There was a small package name issue. Thanks for your help.